# Neural Network on the Iris dataset convergaes very quickly

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, iris-dataset

I'm tasked with writing a ANN using only NumPy (no TensorFlow, PyTorch , etc.) on the iris dataset. I'm running 2000 epochs and it seems by the time of epoch 40 the accuracy of the network stays at 0.66. Also the parameters while debugging are either extremely high or extremely low (for example, for `self.layers[0]`, the `self.output` parameter is `[-59.2447737,-79.13719157,-57.27055739,117.26796309,127.71775426]` on epoch 400.

My network has 4 input nodes, a single hidden layer with 5 nodes and an output layer with 3 nodes corresponding to the 3 types of irises.

I'm confused as to why that's the case. The learning rate is low (0.01), the `weights` and `biases` vectors are initialized with low values, and I normalized the input data.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated. My code:

main.py:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from network import NeuralNetwork
from layer import Layer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iris = load_iris() 
    data, target, target_names = iris.data, iris.target, iris.target_names
    scaler = StandardScaler()

    # One hot encoding to ap the target array to match the 3 neurons output structure
    one_hot_targets = []
    for i in range(len(target)):
        vec = np.zeros(len(target_names))
        vec[target[i]] = 1
        one_hot_targets.append(vec)
    one_hot_targets = np.array(one_hot_targets)
    
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, one_hot_targets, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)    
    learning_rate = 0.01

    # Init a network and add it's layers. Input layer is represented by the input, and not by an actual layer
    network = NeuralNetwork(learning_rate)
    network.add_layer(Layer(4, 5)) # hidden layer 1
    network.add_layer(Layer(5, 3)) # output layer

    # Train the network for a number of epochs
    network.train(X_train_scaled, Y_train, epochs=2000)

    # Test for the test data seperated earlier
    output, accuracy = network.test(X_test_scaled, Y_test)

    # Print testing output
    for i in range(len(output)):
        prediction = target_names[np.argmax(output[i])]
        answer = target_names[np.argmax(Y_test[i])]
        print(f"For testing row: {X_test[i]}, the prediction was {prediction} and the answer was {answer}")
    print(f"Network test accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}")
```

network.py:

```
import numpy as np
from utils import calc_error
np.random.seed(10)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.1):
        self.layers = []
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    
    def add_layer(self, layer): 
        # Layers must be added in order
        self.layers.append(layer)
    
    def forward_propagate(self, input):
        output = input
        for layer in self.layers:
            output = layer.forward_propagate(output)
        return output
    
    def back_propagate(self, error):
        for layer in reversed(self.layers):
            error = layer.back_propagate(error)

    def train_iteration(self, input, target):
        output = self.forward_propagate(input)

        # Calculate the error between the output and the target value
        error = output - target

        # Backpropagate the error through the network
        self.back_propagate(error)

        # Update the weights and biases of the layers
        for layer in self.layers:
            layer.weights -= self.learning_rate * layer.d_weights
            layer.biases -= self.learning_rate * layer.d_biases
    
    def train_epoch(self, inputs, targets):
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            x = inputs[i]
            y = targets[i]
            self.train_iteration(x, y)

    def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs=4000):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.train_epoch(inputs, targets)

            if epoch % (epochs / 100) == 0:
                _, accuracy = self.test(inputs, targets)
                print(f"Epoch {epoch} --> Training Accuracy:{accuracy}")
    
    def predict(self, input):
        output = self.forward_propagate(input)
        return output

    def test(self, inputs, targets):
        output, correct = [], 0

        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            x, y = inputs[i], targets[i]
            guess = self.predict(x)

            is_correct = y[guess.argmax()] == 1
            correct += is_correct
            output.append(guess)

        return output, (correct / len(inputs))
```

layer.py:

```
import numpy as np
from utils import sigmoid, deriv_sigmoid
np.random.seed(10)

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_neurons, activation_function=sigmoid, derivative_activation_function=deriv_sigmoid):
        self.weights = np.random.randn(num_inputs, num_neurons) * 0.01
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, num_neurons))
        self.activation_function = activation_function
        self.derivative_activation_function = derivative_activation_function
    
    def forward_propagate(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.output = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.biases
        self.activated_output = self.activation_function(self.output)
        return self.activated_output
    
    def back_propagate(self, error): 
        error = self.derivative_activation_function(error)
        reshaped_input = self.input.T.reshape((np.max(self.input.shape), 1)) # ensures dot product always works
        self.d_weights = np.dot(reshaped_input, error) 
        self.d_biases = np.sum(error, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        self.d_input = np.dot(error, self.weights.T)
        return self.d_input
```

utils.py:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return (1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)))

def deriv_sigmoid(x):
    return np.multiply(x, 1-x)
```

Comment: Have  you tried batch norm, drop outs or augmentations?

Comment: I haven't tried any of those but it seems like they all come to improve the model, whether it's for overfitting in dropouts, augmentations to increase the number of examples or better convegence in batch norm. I don't think any of these are the problem with my network. Before I look into those in improving the network, I first need to get it to work properly and right now, it looks like there's a fundemental error in my code that I can't seem to find.

Comment: have you tried smaller learning rate?

Comment: I have. I did some changes alongside decreasing the learning rate to 0.001 and it seems to converge at a reasonable time.

Answer (score 0):

Your end layer should use softmax activation as you have three classes.
Your first layer should use relu/ leaky relu activation.
You need to give their respective derivative functions as well.

Sigmoid is applicable only for binary classes with end layer having 1 neuron. Intermediate layers cannot have Sigmoid activation function.

To make the point more clear, you have 3 neurons in output layer. So you expect a signal from 3 neurons based on which you can decide the predicted class of one record. This signal comes in the form of logits. When the logits pass through softmax activation they get converted to  probability values one for each class e.g. [0.1, 0.6, 0.2]. Based on this, since the index 1 has highest probability, the predicted class is 2.

Now coming to the problem you will face while trying to implement softmax activation.
The derivative of softmax is jacobian which involves partial derivatives.

Implementing partial derivatives is a bit overkill for the problem at hand. You can safely assume the difference between predictions and one hot encoded target as the gradient of end layer having softmax.

All the best in learning ML.

Comment: Why is it that "Sigmoid is applicable only for binary classes with end layer having 1 neuron"? Sigmoid maps to any number in the range [0,1].

Comment: Sigmoid is approximation of softmax for binary  classes. It gives one single probability and based on threshold you classify either class 1 or class 0. In your case, you need probability of belonging to all three classes of iris which is given by softmax. The class index having highest probability is the class predicted by the model.

Comment: Notice that the Y values are one hot encoded. This with all my code provides an array of size 3 as an output, where the highest value is the network's prediction as to what's the answer. the output matches the 3 classes for irises, corresponding with the numbers (0,1,2), and the activation function is applied to each of the cells in the vector.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about utility of one hot encoding in multiclass classification. Please take a look at https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-entropy-for-classification-d98e7f974451